# Repeat the first date withing a group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I Would like the first date of each group to repeat for the rest of the rows withing each group

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a subquery for that column?

Comment: can you post sample data and how your desired output should look like ?

Comment: Keep in mind that a table has no concept of first. I assume you mean the earliest date? You could use MIN.

Comment: How would i go about it

Comment: @SeanLange yes how would I code that

Comment: Google SQL SUBQUERY and MIN

Comment: thanks Edward Comeau, I have to  use the partition by in the over statement

Comment: You're welcome, I've updated the answer with some more detailed examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use window expressions and grouping;

[FIRST_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx)

You would need to partition by your first column. to get the split of A and B.

For example;

```
with cteTempData
(
      [Code]
    , [Date]
)
as
(
    select 'A',cast('2015-9-4' as date)
    union all select 'A','2015-9-4'
    union all select 'A','2015-9-4'
    union all select 'A','2015-9-16'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-16'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-22'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-22'
    union all select 'B','2015-10-26'
    union all select 'B','2015-10-30'
)

select
      [Code]
    , [Date]
    , FIRST_VALUE([Date]) over (partition by [Code] order by [Date]) as [First_Date]
from cteTempData
```

Using the first_value syntax also allows you to work with other columns in that ordered record....

```
with cteTempData
(
      [Code]
    , [Date]
    , [Comment]
)
as
(
    select 'A',cast('2015-9-4' as date),'One'
    union all select 'A','2015-9-4','Two'
    union all select 'A','2015-9-4','Three'
    union all select 'A','2015-9-16','Four'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-16','Five'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-22','Six'
    union all select 'B','2015-9-22','Seven'
    union all select 'B','2015-10-26','Eight'
    union all select 'B','2015-10-30','Nine'
)

select
      [Code]
    , [Date]
    , FIRST_VALUE([Date]) over (partition by [Code] order by [Date]) as [First_Date]
    , FIRST_VALUE([Comment]) over (partition by [Code] order by [Date]) as [First_Comment]
from cteTempData
```

Comment: yea i think that is correct, I have used the lag/lead function similar to this, a while back

Answer (score 2):

Use MIN() Over ()

```
Declare @Table table (Grp varchar(25),Date date) 
Insert into @Table values
('A','2015-09-04'),
('A','2015-09-05'),
('A','2015-09-10'),
('B','2015-10-04'),
('B','2015-10-05'),
('B','2015-10-10')

Select *
      ,GrpDate = min(Date) over (Partition By Grp)
 From @Table
```

Returns

```
Grp Date        GrpDate
A   2015-09-04  2015-09-04
A   2015-09-05  2015-09-04
A   2015-09-10  2015-09-04
B   2015-10-04  2015-10-04
B   2015-10-05  2015-10-04
B   2015-10-10  2015-10-04
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `MIN` with the `OVER`-clause

```
SELECT t.ColumnA, 
       DateCol = MIN( t.DateCol ) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.ColumnA ),
       OtherColumns
FROM dbo.TableName t
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go with a `CROSS JOIN`  or `FIRST_VALUE`.

```
Declare @Yourtable table (groupCol varchar(25),firstDate date) 
Insert into @Yourtable values
('A','2015-09-04'),
('A','2015-09-05'),
('A','2015-09-10'),
('B','2015-10-04'),
('B','2015-10-05'),
('B','2015-10-10')

  SELECT a.*,b.firstDate
  FROM @Yourtable a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT groupCol,MIN(firstDate) firstDate
                    FROM @Yourtable b 
                    GROUP BY groupCol)b 
  WHERE a.groupCol =b.groupCol
```

OR

```
SELECT a.*,FIRST_VALUE(a.firstDate) OVER (PARTITION BY groupCol ORDER BY groupCol ASC) AS firstDate 
FROM @Yourtable a
```